# How to extract specific dl, dt list elements using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the date, link, and title for news releases from this website (in Japanese):

https://www.rinnai.co.jp/releases/index.html

Here is the code that I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("https://www.rinnai.co.jp/releases/index.html")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all=soup.find_all("dl",)
```

My expected results are:

```
2019年01月09日
/releases/2019/0109/index_2.html
「深型スライドオープンタイプ」食器洗い乾燥機2019年3月1日発売 食器も調理器具もまとめて入る大容量

2019年01月09日
/releases/2019/0109/index_1.html
シンプルキッチンに似合う洗練されたドロップインコンロ 2月1日新発売 耐久性に優れたステンレストッププレート仕様のグリルレスコンロ
```

And my actual results are:

```
[<dl>
<dt>2019年01月09日</dt>
<dd>
<a href="/releases/2019/0109/index_2.html">



「深型スライドオープンタイプ」食器洗い乾燥機2019年3月1日発売 食器も調理器具もまとめて入る大容量



</a></dd>
</dl>, <dl>
<dt>2019年01月09日</dt>
<dd>
<a href="/releases/2019/0109/index_1.html">



シンプルキッチンに似合う洗練されたドロップインコンロ 2月1日新発売 耐久性に優れたステンレストッププレート仕様のグリルレスコンロ



</a></dd>
</dl>, <dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to complicate this and you are half way there already. You can just iterate through `all` and get the data you want from each `dl`. You can then choose to print or save this to a list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("https://www.rinnai.co.jp/releases/index.html")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
all=soup.find('div',id='index_news').find_all("dl")
#uncomment below line if saving to a list
#all_data=[]
for dl in all:
    date=dl.find('dt').text.strip()
    link=dl.find('a')['href'].strip()
    title=dl.find('a').text.strip()
    print(f'{date}\n{link}\n{title}\n')
    #instead of printing you can save it to a list if you want
    #uncomment below line if saving to a list
    #all_data.append([date,link,title])
```

Output:

```
2019年01月09日
/releases/2019/0109/index_2.html
「深型スライドオープンタイプ」食器洗い乾燥機2019年3月1日発売 食器も調理器具もまとめて入る大容量

2019年01月09日
/releases/2019/0109/index_1.html
シンプルキッチンに似合う洗練されたドロップインコンロ 2月1日新発売 耐久性に優れたステンレストッププレート仕様のグリルレスコンロ

...
```

Comment: This work great. The last item in the output is: `code` ['ニュースリリース', '2019/index.html', '2019年'], which is not a news release. Is there a way to limit the output such that it only contains dl items within `code` <div id="index_news" class="section topics_fmt">?

Comment: @cyoung1989 Updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the headlines by scraping under the `index_news` `div`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.rinnai.co.jp/releases/index.html').text, 'html.parser')
results = [[i.find('dt').text, *(lambda x:[x.a['href'], x.text])(i)] for i in d.find('div', {'id':'index_news'}).find_all('dl')]
```

Output (first two news articles):

```
[['2019年01月09日', '/releases/2019/0109/index_2.html', '\n2019年01月09日\n\n\n\n\n\n「深型スライドオープンタイプ」食器洗い乾燥機2019年3月1日発売 食器も調理器具もまとめて入る大容量\n\n\n\n\n'], ['2019年01月09日', '/releases/2019/0109/index_1.html', '\n2019年01月09日\n\n\n\n\n\nシンプルキッチンに似合う洗練されたドロップインコンロ 2月1日新発売 耐久性に優れたステンレストッププレート仕様のグリルレスコンロ\n\n\n\n\n'].....]
```

Comment: Thats an awesome answer, but care to expand the code for beginners to understand?